What is the difference between x-amz-apigw-id , x-amzn-requestid , x-amzn-trace-id
How these ids differ ?
x-amz-apigw-id , x-amzn-requestid , x-amzn-trace-id

When & Who assign them ?
Where each of them will be useful ?
If I want to use a correlationId which one would be useful ?

I think, "x-amz-apigw-id" :  API Gateway-specific debugging -
" x-amzn-requestid" :  for service-level debugging -
"x-amzn-trace-id" : Best for full request tracing across multiple services (recommended for correlation ID).

x-amz-apigw-id : This is a unique identifier assigned by API Gateway for each request that passes through API Gateway. Assigned by AWS API Gateway Created when a request is processed by API Gateway. Useful for debugging or logging in the context of API Gateway and helps you track the specific execution flow for API Gateway requests.
x-amzn-requestid : This header contains the unique request ID assigned by the underlying AWS service (like Lambda, S3, etc.) that is invoked via the API Gateway.  The AWS service handling the request (e.g., AWS Lambda, S3, etc.) It is generated whenever the AWS service processes a request. Helpful for debugging or logging within the specific AWS service context. If you have issues at the service level, this ID can be used to trace the request through AWS support or CloudWatch logs.
x-amzn-trace-id : This header is part of the AWS X-Ray tracing system. It provides a unique trace identifier that allows you to track the full request path across multiple AWS services, including API Gateway, Lambda, and other AWS services. AWS X-Ray (can be initiated by the client or automatically generated by AWS) It is generated when X-Ray tracing is enabled and a request moves through different AWS services. This is crucial for distributed tracing, helping you visualize and debug the entire request journey across multiple services in a microservices architecture. It's particularly useful when you need to trace the flow of a request through various components and see where bottlenecks or errors occur.
I think x-amzn-trace-id best options. Because  If your goal is to correlate logs and traces across multiple AWS services, x-amzn-trace-id is the best choice. It allows you to track the request from entry to exit across different AWS services, giving you a comprehensive view of the request lifecycle.
x-amzn-requestid is alternative  also. If you are only interested in tracking requests within a specific AWS service, then x-amzn-requestid might be useful. However, it won't give you the full end-to-end trace like x-amzn-trace-id does.
